# Good writing books for Cambridge FCE and CAE candidates?

Tags: discussion

Well, I've just finished the Cambridge PET course (surprisingly, I was awarded with "pass with distinction") and now I'm studying for the Cambridge FCE course. I realised that the abilities required to write essays in PET is far lesser than FCE. In PET, we merely have a compulsory objective on writing an informal letter (around 30 words) and another objective to choose among two given choices (a short story and also an informal letter, around 100 words).

I have this book "IGCSE English as a Second Language" by Alison Digger, and this is probably the best letters writing book I have ever had. I like the fact that the book places huge emphasis on Informal and Formal letters (though, it still has little information other kinds of writings (articles & reviews), but I personally think it's not sufficient). The book explains step by step and points out common blunders made by candidates and also provides ample of essay examples.

Back to the original topic, I'm now looking for writing books which consist of really helpful information that might assist me in scoring Grade A in Cambridge FCE and CAE. To clear ambiguity, I would only like books which provide the following information (apologies if I sound too critical).

- Essay (part 1 in the writing papers of FCE and CAE) (I'm really weak in this particular area)
- Article
- (Formal/Informal) letter or email
- Review
- Report
- Proposal

Comment: Hi David. I've moved this over to our meta site, because requests for resources is explicitly off-topic on the main site. We do have a list of [Resources for learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) that might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know that this might be a possible duplicate of another post. However, I'm specifically looking for "writing books", which is not included in the post you replied.

Comment: The writing section is only 25% of the exam, don't exclude or underestimate the difficulty in the Reading, the Use of English, the Listening or the Speaking. Cambridge course book: [First Trainer](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/cambridgeenglish/catalog/cambridge-english-exams-ielts/first-trainer-2nd-edition/) is not bad at all. Lots of writing practice with good clear examples. It covers the entire spectrum of the exam though.

Comment: Here is a pdf file that allows you to make a valuation of the product. I know it has helped many candidates to pass their exam. https://www.scribd.com/doc/294666106/First-Trainer

Comment: @ColleenV If the question is off topic for the main site, moving it to meta support should not be your go-to solution. There may be rare exceptions, but if this is off topic, it should simply be closed.

Comment: @RobertCartaino This was a well-written question by a new user and some of our community has shown an interest in helping with these sorts of question in the past. If I migrate it here instead of just closing it on the main site, it can be closed as a duplicate of our resources thread, which makes it easier to find, and gives us a nudge to update it. Our meta site isn't that busy, so I don't see a problem with letting it be here for a few days.

Comment: @ColleenV Sounds good. Thank you for the info.